# object is not callable in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

**Is it possible to print output in defined array.**

data is consisted on suppose 10 values and want to expand equal to dimension

```py
import numpy as np
W = 17
cen = 80
dim = 20
E= np.zeros((dim))
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = E((cen - np.round(W*2.21*2)) + np.round(i*2.21*2))
    print(data)
```

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

but it shows output if i remove E.

in MATLAB its written like this

```
W = 17
cen = 80
dim = 20
E=zeros(1,dim);
for i=1:length(data)
    E((center-round(W*2.21*2))+round(i*2.21*2))=data(i);
end
```

any idea?

Comment: You define `Exp` as an array.  It cannot be used as a function: with `(...)`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You should use index/slice notation to access members of the array `Exp[i]`

Comment: Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [array is not callable in python "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680712/array-is-not-callable-in-python-numpy-ndarray-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to print output in defined array.**

Yes. The following code works just fine and prints the zero array.

```py
import numpy as np
Exp = np.zeros(6)
for i in range(len(Exp)):
    print(Exp)
```

The error you are receiving is related to the `Exp(i*2+2)` where you are attempting to call the array like a function.

Comment: @EnzoBnl possibly... I originally thought they were looking for a 2D array. I see that isn't the case now, but I don't really know what they want.  The point of the example code was that printing just the array works. More details would be needed in the question to actually have code that does what was desired.